# traceroute for HTTP

Tags: http, traceroute

I'm trying to track down an elusive issue where a particular URL refuses to work. My investigations so far suggests there's some kind of DPI firewall/proxy/whatever between the client and server that looks at the path of the request and refuses based on that, and I'd like to known where that one is so I know who to contact to resolve the issue. In short

```
curl http://server/path   # FAILS with HTTP 401 Access Denied
curl https://server/path  # WORKS
(client on another network)# curl http://server/path  # WORKS
curl http://server/another_path # WORKS
```

So I'm wondering if there is some kind of traceroute-like tool that would work with HTTP. Basic traceroute doesn't work, because I can't tell traceroute to send a well-formed HTTP request with the particular `path` that is causing problems. I found https://github.com/watson/http-traceroute but that tracks only HTTP redirects, and doesn't help with this particular issue. Any ideas?

**EDIT** No, the `server` is not managed by me. It's a publicly accessible server managed by another organization entirely.

Comment: Are you the administrator of the "server" in question?

Comment: I suppose you did already, but did you check server logs to get more details at why it is responding with a 401 ?

Comment: If you make the target server ('server') add headers to the request, can you see those in the answers (`curl --include`)? Can you also tell by the headers that's indeed another server responding? Otherwise, you can perhaps use `tcpdump` and Wireshark to see if there is a difference in hops between a good and bad answer.

Comment: Nope, I have no access to the server end. Edited the question to make that clear.